# ReferenceError: Cannot access 'web3' before initialization

Tags: node.js, ethereum, web3js, metamask

[chrome-browser-output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZ6mf.png)
[chrome-console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pC0dz.png)

After installing the create-react-app package and then creating the web3.js file and adding the console.log(web3.version) to the App.js file im getting the above error and im not sure how to fix it and to get it working.

Ive also tried the following and it still throws the same error.

```
window.addEventListener('load', async () => {
// Modern dapp browsers...
if (window.ethereum) {
    window.web3 = new Web3(ethereum);
    try {
        // Request account access if needed
        await ethereum.enable();
        // Acccounts now exposed
        web3.eth.sendTransaction({/* ... */});
    } catch (error) {
        // User denied account access...
    }
}
// Legacy dapp browsers...
else if (window.web3) {
    window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    // Acccounts always exposed
    web3.eth.sendTransaction({/* ... */});
}
// Non-dapp browsers...
else {
    console.log('Non-Ethereum browser detected. You should consider trying MetaMask!');
}
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Error can  happen if you haven't called `window.ethereum.enable();` yet.